# Python subfolder listings

Tags: python, file

I have one main directory called **Forfun**. Inside this directory, there are 7-8 sub-directorates as **Test1**, **Test2**, **Test3** and so on. Note there are some files in **Forfun** as well, that are not sub-directorates. For example, there's a .txt file lying inside **Forfun** at the same level as the Test1, Test2 subdirectories.

Every **TestX** sub-directory is further divided into 3 sub-directories, namely: **inputs**, **results** and **parameters**.

I want to be able to list all the instances of a particular folder like **inputs**.

The code should recursively go thru the entire **Forfun** directory and list where all it found the **inputs** or **results** directory.

I tried using `os.listdir` like this:

```
path = '/myfiles/Forfun'
folders = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('inputs')]
folders
```

But this returns me an empty list. Hope I explained the problem clearly, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.listdir()` lists all files and directories in the provided directory. As you've experienced, it does not perform a recursion. It stays on the level of the initially provided directory.

In order to recursively go through a directory tree and iterate through **all** files and directories below a certain directory level, you should use Python's `os.walk()`:

```
import os

def listdirs(suffix):
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
        for subdirname in dirnames:
            subdirpath = os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)
            if subdirpath.endswith(suffix):
                yield subdirpath


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for d in listdirs('inputs'):
        print d
```

I've set up the same directory structure you've been proposing. This is the output of the code above:

```
$ python test.py 
./Test1/inputs
./Test2/inputs
```

Comment: Can we put the `subdirpath` in an array or some storage element to use with some command later? I want to pass those paths thru `os.system(rmdir "path" \s\q)`

Comment: Of course. Do something like `deldirs = [d for d in listdirs('inputs')]`. There are many other ways. Given that you have populated `deldirs` (the list of directories you want to delete), I'd recommend using `shutil.rmtree()` for deletion: `for d in deldirs: shutil.rmtree(d)`

Answer (score 1):

To precise a bit [Jan-Philip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/145400/jan-philip-gehrcke)'s solution:

```
>>> import os
>>> for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    if 'inputs' in dirs:
        print os.path.join(root, 'inputs')
```

That will list all occurrences of `inputs` subfolders.

Comment: This code gives me an error: `invalid syntax` pointing at `os.path`

Comment: there should be a indentation before if. thats why it is giving syntax error.

Comment: Instead of printing out the paths, can we save them in an array?

Comment: @thavan: no, it's a direct copy-paste from IDLE. @dawnoflife: sure, create a list (`l = []`) before the loop, and append instead of printing (`l.append(os.path.join(root, 'inputs'))`).